# Making a custom launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

Followed this tutorial.

[FROM TUTPLUS](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358)

Tut seems very simple and logical, the annoying part is, it just don't work(although everything seems to make sense).

when i click the home button my app wont run, neither i get any option to select among the default launcher app and my app, i can see the app among launcher app when i go to settings>home.

I did provide filters as given in tutorial.

```
<activity
android:name=".HomeActivity"
android:label="Bawa launcher"
android:theme="@style/apptheme"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit late, may help others. In phone's settings, selecting the default launcher to your launcher will solve the problem. In my case, above code worked by this method.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfect in your code. All you need to do is remove:

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`